# $\arctan(\tan(-\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}))+\operatorname{arccot}(\cot(-\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}))=?$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

We know that $$\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}\arctan(-x)=-\arctan(x)$$ $$\arccot(-x)=\pi-\arccot(x)$$ $$\cot(-x)=-\cot(x)$$ $$\tan(-x)=-\tan(x)$$So I have figured out that $$\arctan(\tan(-\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}))=\arctan(-\tan(\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}))=-\arctan(\tan(\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}))=-\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5},$$ $$\arccot(\cot(-\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}))=\arccot(-\cot(-\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}))=\pi-\arccot(\cot(\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}))=\pi-\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}.$$Coming from these, I have solved the problem as follows:$$\arctan(\tan(-\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}))+\arccot(\cot(-\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}))=-\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}+\pi-\frac{3\cdot \pi}{5}=-\frac{6\cdot \pi}{5}
+\pi=-\frac{\pi}{5}.$$But the book says it is incorrect. Could somebody point out where I have made a mistake?

Comment: Keep in mind that $\arccot$ is not supported in $LaTeX$ and it can only be supported in documents, using : - \DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot} - in the preamble of them.

Comment: If so how could I denote arccot in LaTeX?

Comment: You cannot denote arccot in $LaTeX$ in an environment like here. Only when you're writing a document on a $TeX$ document coder (which has a different structure and you can insert and modify things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all real $x$ we have $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\arctan{x}<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0<\operatorname{arccot}{x}<\pi$.$\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}$

$$\arctan\tan\left(-\frac{3 \pi}{5}\right)+\arccot\cot\left(-\frac{3\pi}{5}\right)=$$
$$=\arctan\tan\frac{2 \pi}{5}+\arccot\cot\frac{2\pi}{5}=\frac{4\pi}{5}$$

Comment: Keep in mind that $\arccot$ is not supported in $LaTeX$ and it can only be supported in documents, using : - \DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot} - in the preamble of them.

Comment: @Charalampos Filippatos  I tried. It does not help.

Comment: Could you comment, Michael Rozenberg, how \arctan(tan(-\frac{3\pi}{5}))=\arctan(tan(\frac{2\pi}{5})), and \arccot(\cot(-\frac{3\pi}{5}))=\arccot(\cot(-\frac{2\pi}{5}))?

Comment: @Tug'tekin Because $\tan(\pi+x)=\tan{x}$ and $\cot(\pi+x)=\cot{x}$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think the reason was that the definition (using DelcareMathOperator) was *after* the use of the command. (Of course, you could also use `\operatorname{arccot}` instead.)

Comment: Thank you  Martin! :)

Answer (score 2):

The function $\arctan(\tan x)$ returns a “normalized” $x$, that is the unique angle $x'\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ so that $\tan x=\tan x'$.

Since $-3\pi/5<-\pi/2$, but $2\pi/5=-3\pi/5+\pi\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, you have
$$
\arctan\Bigl(\tan\Bigl(-\frac{3\pi}{5}\Bigr)\Bigr)=\frac{2\pi}{5}
$$
Do similarly for the arccotangent, but with the “normalization” in $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Thanks egreg!..